# Meteor: Different user count on server and client

Tags: javascript, meteor

Why do I get different results for all users on client and server side? On client side it is always 1. Does it matter if I'm logged in? And if this is the case, how can I get all data while I'm logged in?

```
Console Server: Users.find().count() = 7
Console Client: Users.find().count() = 1
```

**shared/collections.js**

```
Users = Meteor.users;
```

**client/router.js**

```
Router.route('/users', {
    name: 'users',
    data: function() {
         return {
            usersAll: Users.find({})
         }
    }
});
```

**template**

```
<template name="users">
    <ul class="list">
        {{#each usersAll}}
            <li><a href="/user/{{_id}}">{{profile.name}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

In the template I just get one result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does matter that you are logged in. You have to publish and subscribe to data on the client. If you attempt to do `Meteor.users.find()` on the client, you will always return the currently active user. (if any)

If you do `Meteor.users.find()` on the server you will return ALL users, regardless of the publication/subscription. It's a security precaution, to keep regular users from accessing private information on the client.

You can publish more or less data to the client if you choose. Check this article out:
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Or the documentation:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish

You can always add the `autopublish` package if you want to publish all data. This is not recommended for production apps though.

**Server**

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function(){
    return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

**Client**

```
Template.users.onCreated(function(){
    var instance = this;

    instance.autorun(function(){
         var allUsers = instance.subscribe('allUsers');
    });
});

Template.users.helpers({
    'usersAll': function(){
        return Meteor.users.find().fetch();
    }
});
```

Comment: But how do I have to publish and subscribe. If I do that, I get the error, that user is already published/subscribed. Could you please give an example?

Comment: But if I now want to update an entry from this usersAll-collection, then I get the error `insert failed: Access denied`. Although I set Users.allow();

Comment: Publishing and subscribing data is only relevant for displaying data. If you want to manipulate the database now, that is entirely different. Please investigate and research on stackoverflow as I'm confident you will find what you need. If not, post a new question with all the relevant code and I'm happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really searched for some hours on that topic. But I think I'm searching for the wrong things. I want to create a little admin frontend on which I can display a list of all users and to edit user-data (like roles). But unfortunately the users-collection acts totally different from any other collection. And that is a problem for me. Maybe you know a few SO-links?